# Draft data is not clearing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, asking-questions, draft

I'm having a problem where questions I've asked previously, and posted, are sticking around in the edit dialog box on SO.

Basically, all the question text and subject are still shown when  from the previous question when I click "Ask Question", even though the previous question was posted.  I'm unsure if clearing out the data and entering new data will modify my previous question or not.  It's very confusing.

EDIT:

I went ahead and cleared out the old data, and entered my new data.  It seems to have posted a new question.  Also, this time it correctly cleared everything so going to "Ask Question" again shows an empty view.

Strange bug though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get exactly one draft for asking, and one draft for answering, at any given time. So the next time you

- post a question
- answer a question

The previous draft is cleared.

Drafts exist for about a week, so if you begin asking a question then never finish, you will get the ask draft the next time you begin asking (but do not complete) a question for that week.

(however as you noted, it *should* clear your draft when you successfully ask a question.. I'll have Sam double check that)

Comment: My guess is there's some edge case I triggered that did not clear it.  Maybe because i used the back button or something else.

Comment: @Mystere I just reviewed the code, only one code path clears drafts and it is triggered every time a question is posted. Only edge case I can think of is that you had the question open in multiple tabs for some reason.

Comment: That's a possibility.  I may have started working on it in one tab, then later clicked 'ask question' again and was brought back to it and continued.  THen posted it.  Later, i then just navigated away from the question as i had originally wrote it, but that somehow retained the data...