# 'Ask Question' button on Stack Overflow populates with a previous question

Tags: support, asking-questions, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Ask a Question” question box has previously asked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/ask-a-question-question-box-has-previously-asked-question)

IE7, Windows Server 2003 (Terminal Server)
And
IE8, Windows XP SP3

As usual I opened up Stack Overflow (saved credentials) and then tried to 'Ask Question'.  Pressing the button resulted in a previous question that I asked appearing.  This happened both on my local machine and the server.  So then I purged my browsing history, re-opened IE and tried again.  The issue occured again.

Would this be a Stack Overflow bug?  Or is it something on my end?  I haven't made any changes in the last few days.

Answer (score 5):

That would be the save draft functionality.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) for details.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I un-draft the question (its not needed anymore)?

Comment: @John, there is no supported way. There is a feature request and a workaround here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/add-an-option-to-save-draft-and-or-reset-draft-manually, but the request was declined.

Comment: @JohnM Also for your reading pleasure, there is an [edge case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71290/draft-data-is-not-clearing/71295#71295 "See waffles comment") in which a draft in multiple tabs or machines will not get discarded properly on posting. That would most likely explain the scenario of seeing the question you just posted, which would otherwise get discarded.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I don't want to risk modifying an already posted question.  What happens if I blank it all and write a new question?

Comment: @Iterator, the new question will overwrite your previous draft. You can only have one draft of a question at a time.