# Is there a way to cancel an answer?

Tags: support, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete the draft posting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67163/how-do-i-delete-the-draft-posting)

I found no way to cancel an unfinished edit. Here is my [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940416/compress-a-series-of-1s-and-0s-into-the-shortest-possible-ascii-string/5957218#5957218). I wrote a couple of lines in the editor, then realized the whole idea was wrong. I couldn't find any 'cancel' button, so I reloaded the page - the edit is still there. I deleted the tab, reopened SO - the edit is still there. I restarted the browser, opened SO - the edit is still there. I started a browser **on a different machine**, opened the page - the edit is still there. I deleted all the text multiple times, reloaded the page - the edit is still there. I deleted the text, then pushed "Post answer", got an error for the empty answer, reloaded the page - the edit is still there. I eventually posted the answer, wrong as it is, in the hopes to then be able to delete it. Is this the only way, or do I have to look till the end of time on my botched attempt of an answer to this question?!

Comment: It only saves one draft so the current workaround is to go to another question and enter some garbage there! See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71290/draft-data-is-not-clearing

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68140/add-a-clear-button-when-a-saved-draft-is-loaded

Comment: Not sure I understand - was it your draft that was saved and continually present? It sounds like you only ever actually posted the answer once.  Screenshots or specific steps to reproduce would help.

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is here. Why not just forget about your answer and leave it where it is?

Comment: Yes, it was the draft that was continually present. I never intended to post it, I only did so eventually to be able to delete the answer and by these crude means get rid of the "draft". Both linked questions answer mine. Poor thing is, I searched meta for "cancel edit" before asking, also looked through the list of existing questions when editing my question, but none matched my question like these two :-/ . I think the designers of SO should re-consider adding a 'cancel' button besides 'post answer', to get these issues out of the way.